# backing up sql database from microsoft sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

i just want to ask if how can i backup my database from sql server 2005 using sql server management studio express? i want a backup it using sql file (**.sql** and not .bak or .mdf) from creating database (if not exist), tables and even the records on the table..thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with one command.  You can script single objects, but I'm not aware of a way to do this in SSMS.  We use SQL Compare from redgate here - it's pretty great.

You can try [powershell](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1842).

Docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx).